# Mediawiki interwiki link not updating?

Tags: mediawiki

After using a particular [interwiki link](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aInterwiki) for a while on my wiki (Mediawiki 1.15.1), the other wiki changed its domain name, and I'd like to update my interwiki links. I changed the URL in the `mw_interwiki` table, but the links aren't updating.

I have tried adding "?action=purge" on the page with the links. I do not appear to have [$wgInterwikiCache](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgInterwikiCache) set in my LocalSettings file, and the `mw_transcache` table has no rows in it.

Is there something else I need to do to trigger an interwiki URL update?

**EDIT** Time solved this problem; after a few hours the links updated, so it's probably a caching issue. Not sure what process would be best to force a cache break if ?action=purge doesn't do it, though.

Comment: Ugh, once I wasted several hours trying to get the bloody iw links to update. I don't remember clearly how I eventually got them to change, but I think one of the maintenance scripts helped, maybe `dumpInterwiki.php`?

Answer (score 1):

Using version 1.4.1 of Extension:Interwiki (on MediaWiki 1.20.2), I had the same problem. Even after deleting the interwiki entry, page previews continued to use the previously-stored value.

Upgrading to Interwiki 2.2 20120425 caused my next interwiki edit attempt to fail, but I was able to delete the entry and recreate it; after that, the links finally updated.

Answer (score 0):

Use Extension:Interwiki to do the change. It will update the links instantly.